# Searching for text within dba_source with regexp_like

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to search every text that will be between 'FROM' and 'WHERE' in `dba_source`, i don't know what patern i need to use in regexp_like to get expected result.

that doesn't works at all:

```
select * from dba_source v
where regexp_like (upper(v.text), '(FROM)+\w+(WHERE)');
```

any ideas what im doing wrong?

some examples:

in dba_source.text:

```
'FROM someschema.table WHERE[...]'
'FROM someschema2.table2, someschema3.table3 WHERE[...]'
'FROM someschema4.table4 WHERE[...]'
```

i want to get result just:

```
'someschema.table'
'someschema2.table2, someschema3.table3'
'someschema4.table4'
```

Comment: Please show some sample data.  This looks messy to me.

Comment: I don't understand, the regexp is in the WHERE clause. If you want to extract data it should be in the SELECT part, please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use wildcards in your pattern. The first query will find any rows that has FROM and WHERE in the etxt column and the second column will extract what is between the FROM and WHERE, so select the best one depending on what you want.

```
SELECT * FROM dba_source v
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (v.text, 'FROM .* WHERE', 'i'); 

SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(v.text, 'FROM (.*) WHERE',1 ,1 ,'i', 2)
FROM dba_source v
```

The `'i'` parameter makes the search case insensitive and the last parameter in the second example means that it is the second group that should be matched

Comment: in first select you forgot about `upper(v.text)`, and it works like i want :) In second select query returns nulls. Thanks!

Comment: @Potato, like I wrote, the `'i'` parameter makes the match case insensitive so you should not need to call `UPPER`

Comment: You dont' need the starting and ending `.*`, as `regexp_substr` will happily search the pattern in any part of the string. Also, you don't need to capture the first and last part of the pattern, ony the middle matters to the OP

Comment: @GMB thanks for catching the starting and ending `.*`, I removed one of them but forgot the rest. I am not sure how to match only the middle part without also including the surrounding `FROM/WHERE`?

Comment: You need them in the pattern, but you don't need to capture them ; remove the `()` around them - see my answer

Comment: @GMB Thanks, got it.

Comment: Welcome @JoakimDanielson ; now our answers really look the same... Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Your regex does not make sense, it expects a string like `FROM(a word)WHERE`, without any space in between ; also, it is case-sensitive.

Also, `regexp_like` only checks if a value matches a regex, while I understand that you are looking to actually extract data from the value. Hence, you should use `regexp_substr` instead.

This will extract values between `FROM` and `WHERE`, regardless of the case.

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(v.text, 'FROM(.*)WHERE',1 ,1 ,'i', 1) 
FROM dba_source v
```